# Performance impact of indexed view in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexed-view

Does anyone have experience with using indexed view in MS SQL Server 2008?
I am trying to find out how does indexed view affect performance of insert / update statements, that are adding / updating rows in tables, which are being used by the indexed view (assuming the indexed view is a select joining a few tables together). Given that all data that are result of the view's underlying select are indexed, I am guessing that there has to be some 'triggers' behind the scenes that update those indexed data when something is added / changed. However I wasn't able to find any useful information on this matter.

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343344/indexed-view-vs-indexes-on-table

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This msdn link is the last word on the subject:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx

For your specific question, pay special attention to the "Design Considerations" section, specifically the "Maintenance Cost Considerations" sub-section.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's useful enough to think of the indexed view as being supported by triggers by the system. The performance implications should be similar.