# How to index all foreign keys in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, foreign-keys

We have large MS SQL database with many tables and foreign keys. We need to index all foreign keys in our tables due to performances and we are trying to avoid do it manually. Is there any way to MS SQL do it automatically or with some tools?

MS SQL server used is MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can find all the foreign keys in your database and then perhaps write a procedure by constructing sql statements to index them to avoid doing it manually.

Comment: Are you sure you really want to index all FK columns in all tables? I would suggest only doing so if the table is going to have more than a couple hundred rows. Otherwise, a scan will still probably be done.

Comment: @Pavanred is right. The code to use depends greatly on the version of SQL Server you are using; post that, and someone may post an example.

Comment: Thanks. It's MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: generate index for all fk

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735407/sql-server-create-indexes-on-foreign-keys-where-necessary

Answer (score 5):

I'd steer you away from trying to do this automatically and encourage you to examine your system (Google missing index DMVs (SQL 2005 or later) for a good start) and create appropriate indexes instead. If you try to do this automatically, you could potentially introduce issues like:

- Creating indexes on columns with low
  cardinality that will consume resources but never be used
  (e.g., a foreign key to a lookup
  table with a small number of possible values)
- Introducing bookmark lookups because
  the indexes you created could have
  benefited from including additional
  columns.

I'm not saying your foreign keys should not be indexed, just that there should be some thought put into the creation of those indexes.

Comment: Thanks for advice. We will review all foreign key for indexing. What if there are more foreign keys that need to be indexed? Maybe it is easier to index them all and then drop unnecessary indexes?

Answer (score 0):

This will allow to find all the FKs and their associated columns. If one where so inclined they could write a script that tests cardinality of the tables involved and generate indexes

```
Select rc.constraint_name, table_name,column_name 
from 
    information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS rc
    INNER JOIN information_schema.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE usage
    on rc.constraint_name = usage.constraint_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Script below should help:

```
declare @schemaName varchar(128)
declare @tableName varchar(128)
declare @columnName varchar(128)

declare @refSchemaName varchar(128)
declare @refTableName varchar(128)
declare @refColumnName varchar(128)

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = ''

declare cur cursor for
select sch.name as SchemaName, tab.name as TableName, col.name as ColumnName, ref_sch.name as RefSchemaName, ref_tab.name as RefTableName, ref_col.name as RefColumnName
from sys.foreign_keys fk
join sys.foreign_key_columns fkc on fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
join sys.tables tab on tab.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
join sys.schemas sch on sch.schema_id = tab.schema_id
join sys.columns col on fkc.parent_column_id = col.column_id and fkc.parent_object_id = col.object_id
join sys.tables ref_tab on ref_tab.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
join sys.schemas ref_sch on ref_sch.schema_id = ref_tab.schema_id
join sys.columns ref_col on fkc.referenced_column_id = ref_col.column_id and fkc.referenced_object_id = ref_col.object_id

open cur
fetch next from cur into @schemaName, @tableName, @columnName, @refSchemaName, @refTableName, @refColumnName
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    set @sql = '
    if not exists (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes 
    WHERE name=''IX_' + @schemaName + @tableName + '_' + @columnName + ''' AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(''' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName + ''')) 
    begin
        CREATE INDEX IX_' + @schemaName + @tableName + '_' + @columnName + ' ON [' + @schemaName + '].[' + @tableName + '] 
        ([' + @columnName + ']) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 80) 
    end'
    --print @sql
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    fetch next from cur into @schemaName, @tableName, @columnName, @refSchemaName, @refTableName, @refColumnName
end

close cur
deallocate cur
```

After selecting all foreign keys it creates indexes with name formated like 'IX_"schemaName""tableName"_"columnName"' and fillfactor = 80.