# sql server : create indexes on foreign keys where necessary

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have lots of tables with foreign keys and some have an index while others have not.
All foreign keys are named `FK_<name of the foreign key>` with indexes named `IX_<name of the foreign key>`.

Are there some good practices, given the column cardinality of the foreign key, to create (or not) indexes ?
Could this be scripted as T-SQL commands ?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question, see this observation in Darren's answer: *"Your question is a little ambiguous, so I am unsure if you are also asking if it is okay to index all of the foreign keys."*

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It does not matter if they are created via a T-SQL Script or via the Designer.  Your question is a little ambiguous, so I am unsure if you are also asking if it is okay to index all of the foreign keys. However, if you are, indexes should be created on columns that are referenced frequently in queries and you can do the following to improve performance:

- Run the database tuning wizard which will supply a summary of improvements and recommend indexes.
- Index all of the foreign keys and run the execution plan (To see if queries are performing faster or slower).

To create an index via `T-SQL`:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_INDEX_NAME
ON Table (FieldName);
```

To get a list of all Foreign keys:

```
SELECT f.name AS ForeignKey, 
 OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS TableName, 
 COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS ColumnName, 
 OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS ReferenceTableName, 
 COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS ReferenceColumnName 
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f 
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
```

To generate a script that applies indexes across all foreign keys you could do this:

```
SELECT 'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + f.name + '] ON ' + OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) + '(' + COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) + ')]'
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f 
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc 
ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx

Comment: I clarified the question, I want to do this using T-SQL script

Comment: `To generate a script that applies indexes across all foreign keys` -- What about just foreign keys with a certain cardinality?

Answer (score 1):

Great work everyone, very helpful.

Adding an enhancement that includes the table schema.  You can also exclude FK names if you prefer (I tend not to add indexes on small tables)

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT TOP 99 PERCENT
            f.name AS ForeignKeyName

        , s.name 
                + '.'
                + OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) 
                + '.'
                + COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) 
            ParentTable

        , referencedSchema.name
                + '.'
                + OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id)
                + '.'
                + COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id)
            ReferencedTable

        , 'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + f.name + ']'
                + ' ON ' 
                    + '[' + referencedSchema.name + ']'
                    + '.'
                    + '[' + OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) + ']'
                    + '(' 
                        + COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) 
                    + ')'
            CreateIndexSql          

    FROM 
        sys.foreign_keys AS f 
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.OBJECT_ID = fc.constraint_object_id
        inner join sys.schemas s on f.schema_id = s.schema_id

        inner join sys.tables referencedTable on f.referenced_object_id = referencedTable.object_id
        inner join sys.schemas referencedSchema on referencedTable.schema_id = referencedSchema.schema_id

    ORDER BY
        2, 3, 1 
) a
where a.ParentTable not in (
    -- Add any exclusions here so you can forget about them
      ''
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @toepoke.co.uk answer and a SQLShack [post here](https://www.sqlshack.com/index-foreign-key-columns-sql-server/), here is a synthesized solution for a script to create all missing indexes on FK.

```
CREATE TABLE #TempForeignKeys
    (
        TableName VARCHAR(100)
       ,ForeignKeyName VARCHAR(100)
       ,ObjectID INT
    )

--check foreign keys that do not have indexes
INSERT INTO #TempForeignKeys
            SELECT OBJ.name, ForKey.name, ForKey.object_id
            FROM   sys.foreign_keys ForKey
                   INNER JOIN sys.objects OBJ ON OBJ.object_id = ForKey.parent_object_id
            WHERE  OBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0

CREATE TABLE #TempIndexedFK
    (
        ObjectID INT
    )

INSERT INTO #TempIndexedFK
            SELECT FK.ObjectID
            FROM   sys.foreign_key_columns ForKeyCol
                   JOIN sys.index_columns IDXCol ON ForKeyCol.parent_object_id = IDXCol.object_id
                   JOIN #TempForeignKeys FK ON ForKeyCol.constraint_object_id = FK.ObjectID
            WHERE  ForKeyCol.parent_column_id = IDXCol.column_id

--SELECT * FROM #TempForeignKeys WHERE ObjectID NOT IN (SELECT ObjectID FROM #TempIndexedFK)
SELECT   *
FROM     (
             SELECT f.name AS ForeignKeyName
                                  ,s.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) + '.'
                                   + COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) ParentTable
                                  ,referencedSchema.name + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) + '.'
                                   + COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) ReferencedTable
                                  ,'CREATE INDEX [IX_' + f.name + ']' + ' ON ' + '[' + referencedSchema.name + ']' + '.'
                                   + '[' + OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) + ']' + '('
                                   + COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) + ')' CreateIndexSql
             FROM   sys.foreign_keys AS f
                    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
                    INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON f.schema_id = s.schema_id
                    INNER JOIN sys.tables referencedTable ON f.referenced_object_id = referencedTable.object_id
                    INNER JOIN sys.schemas referencedSchema ON referencedTable.schema_id = referencedSchema.schema_id
             WHERE  f.object_id NOT IN (
                                           SELECT ObjectID FROM #TempIndexedFK
                                       )
         ) a
ORDER BY 3

DROP TABLE #TempForeignKeys
DROP TABLE #TempIndexedFK
```